# What is this PostgreSQL: Invalid internal value for enum: 1829072 SQL state: 22P03?

Tags: postgresql, enums, pgadmin

Whenever I am doing a `select` query I am getting following error in pgadmin postgreSQL.

```
ERROR:  invalid internal value for enum: 1829072
SQL state: 22P03
```

My psql version is `PostgreSQL 9.6.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.14-1.pgdg16.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is data corruption. Restore your backup. Did you manually manipulate the catalogs, for example to remove an enum value?